# How to conform email using Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, email

Actually in my java application Registration is their so i'm sending mail to User email.

```
<bean id="activateAccountTemplate" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="subject" value="Account activation" />
    <property name="text">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            <html><body><p>Dear %s</p><p>Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/EClass/reset.jsp?a=%s">here</a> to activate your account.</p></body></html>
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So this is working perfectly.After Click the link

```
http://localhost:8080/EClass/reset.jsp?a=tdpTA3Dz8DYSI+9F/DpMxmxGD/a1Kl+3oYqXc1NNH0U=
```

Hear i'm using Encryption Mechanisum.

And my Database have column like..`S_id, username, password, active(T/F)`.

My Requirement is When ever register `Active` always `F(false)` but after click the link `active` will be `true`(When ever Active is true then only Login allowed).

So How to do in reset.jsp? Actually my thinking is

1. Write a controller for this and update `Active` column is `True`(But how to get sid for this)
2. Getting SID, Actually encrypt key shown above will generate so this key will be Decrypt and send to controller and using DB Query select particular user and set active true.(But hear also how to get url key... `request.getParameter(?)` )

Please give me suggestion... i'm stuck how to do this..

Give some sample code on `reset.jsp`

**EDIT** : Actually i'm following MVC Principle so with out reset.jsp how to write direct controller class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reset.jsp could be something like this :

```
<%
    String token = request.getParameter("a");

    // Connection to DB executing this query :
    // "UPDATE users SET active = true WHERE S_id = " + token
%>
```

Since you have probably already code to access your database, I wont include this example part, but it put you on the right track. It would also be really useful to catch if there is one row updated and return information to user if it has worked properly, if no row updated, to verify their URL.

Hope this help.

**EDIT :**

Same method as a Servlet :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Reset extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                               throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = request.getParameter("a");

    // Connection to DB executing this query :
    // "UPDATE users SET active = true WHERE S_id = " + token

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println("<HTML><BODY>Your response to the user depending on rows updated from SQL</BODY></HTML>");
  }
}
```

You will also need to define in web.xml :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>reset</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>myservlets.reset</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>reset</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/reset</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And change your link :

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/EClass/reset?a=%s">here</a>
```

**EDIT :**

Same method as Spring Controler :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/activation"
public class AccountActivationController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@RequestParam("a") String token, ModelMap model) {
        // Connection to DB executing this query :
        // "UPDATE users SET active = true WHERE S_id = " + token

        return successful ? "activationSuccessful" : "activationError";
    }
}
```

Can't help much since I've never done Spring before...

Comment: Actullay i'm usig MVC, so if it is possibly to write Direct Contrllor class with out using reset.jsp

Comment: I've updated the answer. Also I think activation would be a better name than reset of course!

Comment: Thank for your replay.. But i'm using in Spring so is it possible to Create some controller class and do all DB stuff hear?..

Comment: I've added sample Spring Controler code from my research since I've never developped in Spring and also it is not tested.

Comment: thanks, last one... is it necessary to write web.xml servelet tag?

Comment: No, with annotations your controller will be declared! :) I'm more a JSF developper but this is almost the same principle.

Answer (score 1):

You should make active and other stuffs into a separate table.

```
table user

id   username   password


table activation

id active expired_time token user_id
```

Once a user completes the sign up, there is one record should be insert into the activation table. active field is false and expired time is 2 hours after now, etc.

Then use the token to look up the table and do the active work.

Comment: oh.. Thankyou so much for this idea.. i'm forgot this one... Please help me how to write spring controller using request url?